# How to get generated keys using SimpleJdbcInsert and executeBatch with MYSQL JDBC driver?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I want to insert multiple records at a time and get the id of each record which is auto-increment. I am doing in following way but getting number of updated rows instead of generated key which is id in this case.

```
public int[] addPersons(List<Person> persons)
{
   SqlParameterSource[] records= new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource[persons.size()] ;

    int i = 0;
    for (Person person: persons) 
   {
         records[i]= new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(person);
         i++;   
    }

  SimpleJdbcInsert insertPerson=new SimpleJdbcInsert(dsource).withTableName("PersonTable").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
 int [] ids= insertPerson.executeBatch(records);

  return ids;
}
```

Here Person is the bean.
So how can I get the auto generated key which is id, for the records added ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring JDBC does not allow to retrieve the generated keys when you invoke `executeBatch` method. This is because internally it invokes `executeBatch()` method of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, which only returns the count of rows affected. An alternate approach would be to execute the `insert` statement using `executeAndReturnKey` method multiple times.

Comment: Right now I am doing using executeAndReturnKey  only, but I think it is not the best practice to do in this way because it will unnecessary increase the number of transactions and keeps server busy.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but we have a limitation with the API :(